# Sign in with web service

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I can't sign In with webService in my android app, in have an exception of timeOut

my activity:

```
RetrofitClient.instance.loginUser(login.getText().toString().trim(),password.getText().toString().trim()).enqueue(object :Callback<DefaultResponse>{
      override fun onFailure(call: Call<DefaultResponse>, t: Throwable) {
          Toast.makeText(applicationContext,t.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


      }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<DefaultResponse>, response: Response<DefaultResponse>) {
        if(response.code()==200)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,response.message(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }
})
```

my Api:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("auth/Login")
fun loginUser(
        @Field("email")email: String,
        @Field("password")password: String
):retrofit2.Call<DefaultResponse>
```

RetrofitClient:

```
object RetrofitClient {
   val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
          .addInterceptor { chain ->
              val original = chain.request()

              val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                      .method(original.method(), original.body())

              val request = requestBuilder.build()
              chain.proceed(request)
          }
           .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()

    val instance: UserApiService by lazy{

         val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl("http://internship.mobelite.fr:3000/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
    retrofit.create(UserApiService::class.java)

}

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0i13.png)

Comment: "an exception of timeOut", in this case, the backend is too slow, try to update the timeout on your side to 60 seconds

Comment: i update the timeout and change the methode by body and i still have the same problem

Comment: Contact with the backend developers.